# Migrate sitecore 8.1 from lucene to Solr 5.x issue

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to swap lucene with solr in our project
(I use this cool guide [How to switch Lucene to Solr](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2266/how-to-switch-lucene-to-solr))
 But I faced an issue. All except these two fields work fine.

Part of Lucene's config.

```
  <field fieldName="my_project_name" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS" boost="1f" emptyString="_EMPTY_" nullValue="_NULL_" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
          <Analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider"/>
  </field>

  <field fieldName="my_project_type_name" storageType="YES" indexType="TOKENIZED" vectorType="WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS" boost="1f" emptyString="_EMPTY_" nullValue="_NULL_" type="System.String" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
        <Analyzer type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.Analyzers.LowerCaseKeywordAnalyzer, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider"/>
  </field>
```

Part of Solr Config

```
<field fieldName="my_project_type_name" termVectors="true"   termPositions="true" termOffsets="true">ComputedFields.ProjectTypeNameField, Business</field>
<field fieldName="my_project_name" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true">ComputedFields.ProjectNameField, Business</field>
```

According to solr docs I have to add relevant handler 
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-term-vector-component.html
- it doesn't work.
Also I have tried use PostingsHighlighter with this storeOffsetWithPOsitions  - the same result.

The answer is - is there any chance that sitecore support this solr feature? If so what I did in the wrong way? Can it be implemented in the other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see, you skipped some additional configuration.

Should be:

```
<field fieldName="my_project_type_name" termVectors="true" stored="yes" indexType="untokenized" returnType="string"   termPositions="true" termOffsets="true">ComputedFields.ProjectTypeNameField, Business</field>
<field fieldName="my_project_name" termVectors="true" stored="yes" indexType="untokenized" returnType="string" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true">ComputedFields.ProjectNameField, Business</field>
```